# Bitsequence detector counter doesn't work (VHDL)

Tags: vhdl

I build a 4 bit sequence detector with a 16-bit input.
I wanna now how often the sequence appears in the 16 bits.

For that I use this code:

```
LIBRARY ieee;
USE ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
USE ieee.std_logic_unsigned.all;

ENTITY seqdec IS
PORT    (   X:      IN      std_logic_vector(15 DOWNTO 0);
            CLK:    IN      std_logic;
            RESET:IN        std_logic;
            LOAD:   IN      std_logic;
            Y:      OUT std_logic);
END seqdec;

ARCHITECTURE SEQ OF seqdec IS
TYPE        statetype IS (s0, s1, s2, s3, s4);
SIGNAL  state, next_state: statetype;
SIGNAL  counter: std_logic_vector(3 DOWNTO 0) :="0000" ;
SIGNAL  temp:   std_logic_vector(15 DOWNTO 0);
SIGNAL  so:     std_logic;

    BEGIN
    STATE_AKT: PROCESS (CLK, RESET)
        BEGIN   
            IF RESET = '1' THEN     
                state <= s0 ;
                counter <= (OTHERS => '0') ;
            ELSIF CLK = '1' AND CLK'event THEN
                state <= next_state ;
            END IF;
        END PROCESS STATE_AKT;

    PISO:       PROCESS (CLK, LOAD, X)
        BEGIN
            IF (LOAD = '1') THEN
                temp(15 DOWNTO 0) <= X(15 DOWNTO 0);
            ELSIF (CLK'event and CLK='1') THEN
                so <= temp(15) ;
                temp(15 DOWNTO 1) <= temp(14 DOWNTO 0);
                temp(0) <= '0';
            END IF;
        END PROCESS PISO;



    STATE_CAL: PROCESS (so,state)
        BEGIN
            CASE state IS
                WHEN s0 =>  IF so = '0' THEN next_state <= s0  ;
                                ELSE next_state <= s1 ;
                                END IF;
                WHEN s1 =>  IF so = '0' THEN next_state <= s1;
                                ELSE next_state <= s2 ;
                                END IF;
                WHEN s2 =>  IF so = '0' THEN next_state <= s3 ;
                                ELSE next_state <= s2 ;
                                END IF;
                WHEN s3 =>  IF so = '0' THEN next_state <= s0 ;
                                ELSE next_state <= s4 ;
                                END IF;
                WHEN s4 =>  IF so = '0' THEN next_state <= s0;
                                ELSE next_state <= s2 ;
                                END IF;
                WHEN OTHERS => NULL;
            END CASE;
        END PROCESS STATE_CAL;

    STATE_Y: PROCESS (state)
        BEGIN
            CASE state IS
                WHEN s4 =>      
                    Y <= '1'; 
                    counter <= counter + '1';
                WHEN OTHERS =>  Y <= '0' ;
            END CASE;
        END PROCESS STATE_Y;
END SEQ;
```

But neither my counter reset nor my incrementation of counter is working.
The rest is working perfect and fine.

Has somebody a hint or an idea for me?

Comment: The counter increment is in another process than that with the clock and counter reset.  Have you simulated this, or checked synthesis warnings ?  Guess neither...  Use the ModelSim simulator provided with the Altera installation, and pay attention to the synthesis warnings... that will get you a long way...

Comment: Hint: Write one (and only one!) process which describes the counter behavior. That should help you a lot.

Comment: of course, forgot about that fact while writing it.

Answer (score 0):

The programm is now working fine in ModelSim, but I struggle with getting it on the board.

I simulated it several times in ModelSim, with different parameters and it works fine, so the functional part is fine.

My code looks now this way:

```
LIBRARY ieee;
USE ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
USE ieee.std_logic_unsigned.all;

ENTITY seqdec IS
PORT    (   X:          IN      std_logic_vector(15 DOWNTO 0);
            CLK:        IN      std_logic;
            RESET:  IN      std_logic;
            LOAD:       IN      std_logic;
            DIGIT:  OUT std_logic_vector(6 DOWNTO 0) := "1111110";
            COUT:       OUT std_logic_vector(2 DOWNTO 0);
            Y:          OUT std_logic);
END seqdec;

ARCHITECTURE SEQ OF seqdec IS
TYPE        statetype IS (s0, s1, s2, s3, s4);
SIGNAL  state: statetype;
SIGNAL  next_state: statetype:=s0;
SIGNAL  counter: std_logic_vector(2 DOWNTO 0) :="000" ;
SIGNAL  temp:   std_logic_vector(15 DOWNTO 0);
SIGNAL  so:     std_logic := 'U';

-------------------Aktualisierung des Zustandes--------------------------------
    BEGIN
    STATE_AKT: PROCESS (CLK, RESET)
        BEGIN   
            IF RESET = '1' THEN     
                state <= s0;
            ELSIF CLK = '1' AND CLK'event THEN
                state <= next_state ;
            END IF;
        END PROCESS STATE_AKT;

---------------------Counter---------------------------------------------------
    COUNT:  PROCESS (state, RESET)
        BEGIN   
            IF (RESET = '1') THEN   
                counter <= (OTHERS => '0');
            ELSIF (state = s4) THEN
                counter <= counter + '1';
                COUT <= counter;
            END IF;
    END PROCESS COUNT;

-------------------PiSo für die Eingabe des zu Prüfenden Vektors---------------
    PISO:       PROCESS (CLK, LOAD, X)
        BEGIN
            IF (LOAD = '1') THEN
                temp(15 DOWNTO 0) <= X(15 DOWNTO 0);
            ELSIF (CLK'event and CLK='1') THEN
                so <= temp(15);
                temp(15 DOWNTO 1) <= temp(14 DOWNTO 0);
                temp(0) <= '0';
            END IF;
        END PROCESS PISO;

-------------------Zustandsabfrage und Berechnung------------------------------
    STATE_CAL: PROCESS (so,state)
        BEGIN
            CASE state IS
                WHEN s0 =>  IF so = '0' THEN next_state <= s0  ;
                                ELSIF (so = '1') THEN next_state <= s1 ;
                                END IF;
                WHEN s1 =>  IF so = '0' THEN next_state <= s1;
                                ELSIF (so = '1') THEN next_state <= s2 ;
                                END IF;
                WHEN s2 =>  IF so = '0' THEN next_state <= s3 ;
                                ELSIF (so = '1') THEN next_state <= s2 ;
                                END IF;
                WHEN s3 =>  IF so = '0' THEN next_state <= s0 ;
                                ELSIF (so = '1') THEN next_state <= s4 ;
                                END IF;
                WHEN s4 =>  IF so = '0' THEN next_state <= s0;
                                ELSIF (so = '1') THEN next_state <= s2 ;
                                END IF;
                WHEN OTHERS => NULL;
            END CASE;
        END PROCESS STATE_CAL;

-------------------Ausgang-----------------------------------------------------
    STATE_Y: PROCESS (state)
        BEGIN
            CASE state IS
                WHEN s4 =>      
                    Y <= '1'; 
                WHEN OTHERS =>  Y <= '0' ;
            END CASE;
        END PROCESS STATE_Y;

-------------------7 Segment---------------------------------------------------
    SEVEN_SEG: PROCESS (counter, CLK)
        BEGIN
            IF (RESET = '1') THEN
                DIGIT <= "1111110";
            END IF;
            CASE counter IS
                WHEN "000" => DIGIT <= "1111110";
                WHEN "001" => DIGIT <= "0110000";
                WHEN "010" => DIGIT <= "1101101";
                WHEN "011" => DIGIT <= "1111001";
                WHEN "100" => DIGIT <= "0110011";
                WHEN "101" => DIGIT <= "1011011";
                WHEN OTHERS => NULL;
            END CASE;
        END PROCESS SEVEN_SEG;


END SEQ;
```

When i put it on the board the 7-segment will show a "3".
I would assume, as the functional part seems to be good,that it has to do somethink with the timings, but i can't find any solution to it. If some experience VHDL-programmer could give me a new hint that would be great.

Best regards
Adrian